# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: function jsonb_set(json, unknown, unknown) does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am using this query to update a jsonb field

```
UPDATE email_lists SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{aa@rr.com}', '{"email":"aa@rr.com","tnc":"1","add_to_list":"1","country_name":"Mexico","added_at":"2018-06-25"}') WHERE id = '50'
```

But getting this error

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::UndefinedFunction:
>   ERROR:  function jsonb_set(json, unknown, unknown) does not exist

Comment: what postgres version you run?.. jsonb_set comes with 9.5 I think

Comment: I am using 9.6.9, So what would be alternative to jsonb_set ?

Comment: 9.6 should be fine. try `pg_catalog.jsonb_set` (preprend schema name)

Comment: Is your `data` column's type `json` or `jsonb`? The error message suggests that it is the older `json`, not the `jsonb` that `jsonb_set` expects.

Comment: I am working with json and don't want it converted to jsonb. I hoped that I will be able to use `::jsonb` in order to convert json to jsonb before passing it to the function. This should work right?

Comment: ```update XYZ set settings = jsonb_set(settings::jsonb, '{is_smart}', 'true', true)::json``` I got it working. Problem was because of `true` value not wrapped with single quotes `'true'`. Anyway: PG error message is highly misleading!!!!